# What is a quick way to stream and live record video to the Internet using Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, streaming, webcam

I need to set up a webcam to act as a security monitor for a one-off event of around 10 hours.  My key requirement is that the video feed is streaming to the Internet and being *recorded to the Internet* in real-time.  Recording in real-time to the Internet is important, as the camera will be in a relatively unsecure location where it would be possible for someone to access the local computer in real-time and cancel/delete any local and/or delayed recording, and there won't necessarily be anybody monitoring the live stream as it happens.

I'm running Ubuntu.  What's a quick way to get this setup?  Is there a web service that meets these requirements, or is it easy to e.g. configure VLC to do this?

Comment: Basically it just has to make it to an Internet storage location, whether that be in a proprietary format or not, and has to be committing new frames on a fairly regular basis, so if the connection to the local machine gets severed, there's still a persistent copy somewhere that is Internet-accessible containing nearly all of the recorded video.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.area536.com/projects/streaming-video/

this thing uses HTTP, streams live to http. But probably cpu intensive on webcam computer making it kinda audible.

Comment: Damn this doesn't record the stream.

Comment: Really should be in Bryce's comment section (50 rep). No not spam.